# Нейронная сеть, решающая проблему xor, сходится к 0.5

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

Я написал следующую нейронную сеть, решающую проблему xor в c++. Однако вместо нормальных ответов она при любых примерах выдает 0.5. Можете подсказать в чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int Epoch = 100000;
int TrainSet = 4;
double LearningRate = 0.001;
double Moment = 0.4;
double Error = 0;
double Ideal;
double InputN[2];
double HideNInput[2];
double HideNOutput[2];
double OutputNInput[1];
double OutputNOutput[1];
double WeightIH[4];
double WeightHO[2];
double Train[4][3];
double DeltaOut[1];
double DeltaHide[2];
double GradientHO[2];
double GradientIH[4];
double DeltaHO[2];
double DeltaIH[4];
double PastDeltaHO[2] = {0,0};
double PastDeltaIH[4] = {0,0,0,0};


class NN {
public:
    void init() {
        double ra;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                ra = rand() % 100;
                ra = ra / 100;
                WeightIH[i] = ra;
                cout << WeightIH[i]<<" ";
        }    
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        ra = rand() % 100;
        ra = ra / 100;
        WeightHO[i] = ra;
        cout << WeightHO[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
double Sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x));
}


double predict(int a, int b, int c) {
    InputN[0] = a;
    InputN[1] = b;
    Ideal = c;
    HideNInput[0] = 0;
    HideNInput[1] = 0;
    OutputNInput[0] = 0;
    //cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    //cout << HideNInput[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++) {
        HideNInput[0] = HideNInput[0] + WeightIH[i] * InputN[i];
    }
    //cout << HideNInput[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
        HideNInput[1] = HideNInput[1] + WeightIH[i] * InputN[i-2];
    }
    //cout << HideNInput[1] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++) {
        HideNOutput[i] = Sigmoid(HideNInput[i]);
    }
    // cout << HideNOutput[0] << " " << HideNOutput[1] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        OutputNInput[0] = OutputNInput[0] + WeightHO[i] * HideNOutput[i];
    }
    //cout << OutputNInput[0] << endl;
    OutputNOutput[0] = Sigmoid(OutputNInput[0]);
    cout << OutputNOutput[0] << endl;
    Error = ((Ideal-OutputNOutput[0])*(Ideal-OutputNOutput[0])) / 1;
    //cout << Error * 100 << "%" << " " << endl;
    return(OutputNOutput[0]);
    }

void train(int q, int r, int s) {
    InputN[0] = q;
    InputN[1] = r;
    Ideal = s;
    HideNInput[0] = 0;
    HideNInput[1] = 0;
    OutputNInput[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        HideNInput[0] = HideNInput[0] + WeightIH[i] * InputN[i];
    }
    //cout << HideNInput[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++) {
        HideNInput[1] = HideNInput[1] + WeightIH[i] * InputN[i - 2];
    }
    //cout << HideNInput[1] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        HideNOutput[i] = Sigmoid(HideNInput[i]);
    }
    //cout << HideNOutput[0] << " " << HideNOutput[1] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        OutputNInput[0] = OutputNInput[0] + WeightHO[i] * HideNOutput[i];
    }
    //cout << OutputNInput[0] << endl;
    OutputNOutput[0] = Sigmoid(OutputNInput[0]);
    //cout << OutputNOutput[0] << endl;
    //Error = ((Ideal - OutputNOutput[0]) * (Ideal - OutputNOutput[0])) / 1;
    //cout << Error * 100 << "%" << " " << endl;

    DeltaOut[0] = (Ideal - OutputNOutput[0]) * ((1 - OutputNOutput[0])*OutputNOutput[0]);
    //cout << OutputNOutput[0]<<"," ;
    //cout << DeltaOut[0] << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        DeltaHide[i] = ((1 - HideNOutput[i]) * HideNOutput[i]) * (WeightHO[i]* DeltaOut[0]);
        GradientHO[i] = DeltaOut[0] * HideNOutput[i];
        DeltaHO[i] = LearningRate * GradientHO[i] +Moment * PastDeltaHO[i];
        WeightHO[i] = WeightHO[i] + DeltaHO[i];
        PastDeltaHO[i] = DeltaHO[i];
        //cout<< DeltaHide[i] <<","<< GradientHO[i] <<","<< DeltaHO[i] <<","<< WeightHO[i] <<endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        GradientIH[i] = InputN[i] * DeltaHide[0];
        GradientIH[i+2] = InputN[i] * DeltaHide[1];
        DeltaIH[i] = LearningRate * GradientIH[i]+Moment * PastDeltaIH[i];
        DeltaIH[i + 2] = LearningRate * GradientIH[i] +Moment * PastDeltaIH[i + 2];
        WeightIH[i] = WeightIH[i] + DeltaIH[i];
        WeightIH[i+2] = WeightIH[i+2] + DeltaIH[i+2];
        PastDeltaIH[i] = DeltaIH[i];
        PastDeltaIH[i+2] = DeltaIH[i+2];
        //cout << DeltaIH[i] << "," <<  DeltaIH[i + 2] << endl;
    }

    }
};

int main()
{
    int KolTrI;
    int KolTrJ;
    ifstream fileout;// прочитать                
fileout.open("text.txt");
fileout >> KolTrI;
fileout >> KolTrJ;

for (int i = 0; i < KolTrI; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < KolTrJ; j++) {
        fileout >> Train[i][j];
        cout << Train[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
fileout.close();

srand(time(NULL));

NN Neur;

Neur.init();

Neur.predict(1,1,0);
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
for (int m = 0; m < Epoch;m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < TrainSet;n++) {
        Neur.train(Train[n][0], Train[n][1], Train[n][2]);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
    cout << WeightIH[i]<<" ";
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cout << WeightHO[i]<<" ";
}
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
Neur.predict(0,1,1);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002386/)?